# Excel validation list drop-down arrow click event detection

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I want to capture an event when user shows Excel validation list. I know that validation list may be shown by clicking drop-down arrow next to cell containing validation list or when user right clicks on the cell and choose the option from context menu. Both scenarios handling would be awesome, but just "arrow scenario" is great for me too.

In Excel style it would be named something like:

```
BeforeDropDownValidationListShow(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

DropDownValidationListArrowClick // worse, but would be OK too
```

In perfect scenario: user click on small validation list arrow next to cell containing data validation (list type) and:

- the inbuilt list does not show
- just my action (e.g. MessageBox is raised) instead.

It should work on Windows.

**I know that the event not exists, but I would like to create/simulate that behaviour**. I think that I must use something like MouseHooks and propbably detect where the user clicked (screen coordinates) relative to ActiveCell in Excel workbook. But maybe there is some clever and more simple way.

I am VBA programmer and very beginner in C# and VSTO, I know that the task is probably quite hard but possible. Give me some ideas please, I'll try to write code by my own. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you intend to not show the dropdown list you can set Validation.InCellDropdown=False

Comment: No, that's not my purpose. I want to change the original behavior so that when a user clicks on the small arrow to expand the dropdown validation list—the one that appears right next to the cell containing such a validation type. Eugene Astafiev gave me hint that looked great at first, but in the all UI elelemts listed (above 4k elements) there is no the arrow I am looking for.

Comment: So you want to show a message box instead of the list. But why? Maybe the answer could help to find a solution.

Comment: I can see where you're going. I know you're high skilled VBA specialist, but I am too. The desired behaviour I want to achieve is NOT possible in pure Excel or VBA. MsgBox was just an example. If you have idea (maybe using WinAPI) how to create such `onClick` event, please share it here how to achieve that. The question `why` in context of creating event makes no sense in OOP - the events should completely abstracts business logic like in `Inverse of Control` approach.

Comment: What about using an image of an arrow in the adyacent cell of the dropdown list cell? You could assign a macro to that image and that would be kind of an _onclick_ image if user clicks there

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I've tried that, but it's not possible—the original dropdown arrow always appears on top of that shape/image. I must overwrite the behavior of the existing data validation without modifying/deleting the existing list. If possible, I would overwrite (just for a while) the existing data validation with a special UDF function—a relatively little-known trick—and the macro/UDF would automatically be called after someone chooses something from the list. However, **I can't modify/delete the existing list, even temporarily.**

Comment: *the original dropdown arrow always appears on top of that shape/image* There is an option to hide that dropdown when you set it up, and then your arrow image could make the trick

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns How to do that without modifying (even temporarily) existing incell data validation (list type)? Office 2021 here.

Comment: If you cannot modify the existing data validation setup then there is no way because the only way to hide the original arrow is exactly in the setup

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I am allowed to modify only global settings in the host app (Excel), not data validation in each cell/area

Answer (score 0):

You may try to customize the context menu by repurposing controls (replacing the built-in action with your own). Excel like other Office applications uses the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) for customizing the UI. Read more about repurposing built-in controls in the [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

See [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745) for ribbon controls IDs.

Comment: I thought that the ribbon is only "header menu" in Excel, not entire user interface like small arrows next to the cells containing data validation lists (appearing onclick - selection change event). I must check it out in a few days and give the feedback in current topic, thanks!

Comment: No, the Fluent UI is used for customizing context menus.

Comment: Sure. I've just checked the excelcontrols.xlsx list, but unfortunately, I didn't find the small dropdown data validation list arrow there. However, I will check it again tomorrow more carefully.

Comment: Not all ribbon controls are listed there. You may also check the `Customize Ribbon` tab from the settings dialog (see your host application).

Comment: Tried to found this on Office 2021, no luck :( In docs you've sent `Are all the controls in the Office applications available to my own customizations? No, some controls are not available.` seems, no simple way to catch the click event on that arrow element... It looks like it is inbuilt quite low-level into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to "rebuild" all of the functionality of the dropdown list. If you're okay with the dropdown arrow always being shown, you could create an image with the dropdown arrow and assign a macro to it

```
Sub CustomDropdownClicked

'Your pre-dropdown code here

'Your code to show the actual dropdown choices here

End Sub
```

This would mean you'd need to write code that creates/displays an array of images that (dynamically?) get assigned text for the valid values. But you'd get to have full control over the process at that point.

You'd also want to think through how much of the data validation functionality that you need (e.g. enforcing valid choices only, showing a msgbox to help the user understand what is valid, etc.). Might be able to invoke some of that by clever use of built-in data validation that takes a back seat without having to re-write all of that functionality. I.e. hide the built-in dropdown arrow.

Comment: Are you sure, that event `Workbook.BeforeSave` will be fired? You can't be (like Application.EnableEvents = False), and someone can save file with my shapes/images by accident. Workbook should be 100% "untouched" in every critical scenario. The user must be able to write own macros in the file, it may be ordinary xlsx file or xlsm/xlsb.